# How to verify page content after form submitted using Capybara 1.x

Tags: rspec, capybara

I'm writing a feature/integration spec to verify content
after submitting a form on a page.  After the form is submitted,
our code does a redirect (302) to a page with essentially says "Account saved".

I'm running into a race condition to verify the content of the page seen
after the form is submitted.  We're currently still on Capybara 1.1.2 (which our manager wants to stay with).  Here's what I have but, it's passes sometimes and fails sometimes.

```
fill_in 'Some Field', with: 'Some Value'
click_button 'Save'

WAIT_CONDITION
page.should have_content('Account saved')
```

For the line containing, WAIT_CONDITION, I've tried the following,
but they'll either pass inconsistently or sometimes produce an error:

```
# this fails because 'page' sometimes evaluates to page w/ form, not confirmation page
wait_until(5) { page.has_content? 'Account Saved' }

# sometimes generates "NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for "Conflict":String"
wait_until(5) { current_url =~ /#{confirmation_url}$/ }

# sometimes generates "undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass"
wait_until(5) { current_url != /#{form_url}$/ }

# this works, but it's a hack
sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could assume that any exceptions in the wait_until block are due to race conditions and ignore them (ie rescue them). It is still a bit of a hack, but it is better than using sleep.

Try adding a rescue that returns false:

```
wait_until(5) { current_url =~ /#{confirmation_url}$/ rescue false }
```